# Empty iframe after submitting the form

Tags: php, html

Im now learning .php and want to try some basic form. As I created the form for getting embed link from user (youtube), but after submitting the form the iframe content is empty. If anyone knows the cause, please kindly guide me :)

```
<FORM method = 'post' action = 'a.php'>
<input type="text" name = "embed" id= "embed"></input>
<br><input type = 'submit' value = 'Go'>
</form>

<?
echo $_REQUEST['embed'];
?>
```

Comment: what exactly your last code looks like?

Comment: the problem is not in the code you've written here, it's most likely in `a.php`

Comment: I've removed that and the iframe content still empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code, it worked for me. I put everything in one `index.php` file.

```
<?php echo $_REQUEST['embed']; ?>

<form method='post'>
<input type="text" name="embed" id="embed"></input>
<br><input type='submit' value='Go'>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for all answers, but I want user to insert something like this in the text box (whole). Is it possible?

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3tmd-ClpJxA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: Yes, you can but you should be careful with such html code especially iframe tag posting to the backend. I recommend you to post only link to youtube, then you will have control over iframe tag.
I changed my code to your needs, it works for me.